# Using SSL and AntiForgeryToken

Tags: ssl, antiforgerytoken

I am developing a website which forces the user to use HTTPS. Do I need to worry about also using the Html.AnitForgeryToken helper?

Comment: Rather depends on your website. Does your website have any actions that the user can take that might cause issues if someone else pretends to be that user with a Cross-site request forgery attack?

Comment: @Djkgraaf: Yes - this is a membership database application however if I'm using SSL is it possible for someone else to obtain a user's credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is used to protect the transport of the data only. 
The  AntiForgeryToken is used to prevent [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). CSRF attacks are possible with and without HTTPS, which means you still need this protection even if you use HTTPS.